# trend following using meta label issue with time ubtracting `n`, use `n * obj.freq`

Tags: python, pandas, time

I am trying to implement the trend following labeling from asset managment book. I found the following code that I wanted to implement, however I am getting an error

TypeError: Addition/subtraction of integers and integer-arrays with Timestamp is no longer supported.  Instead of adding/subtracting `n`, use `n * obj.freq`

```
!pip install yfinance
!pip install mplfinance
import yfinance as yf
import mplfinance as mpf
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 

# get the data from yfiance 
df=yf.download('BTC-USD',start='2008-01-04',end='2021-06-3',interval='1d')

#code snippet 5.1
# Fit linear regression on close
# Return the t-statistic for a given parameter estimate.
def tValLinR(close):
    #tValue from a linear trend
    x = np.ones((close.shape[0],2))
    x[:,1] = np.arange(close.shape[0])
    ols = sm1.OLS(close, x).fit()
    return ols.tvalues[1]

    #code snippet 5.2
'''
 #search for the maximum absolutet-value. To identify the trend 
  #  - molecule - index of observations we wish to labels. 
   # - close - which is the time series of x_t
   # - span - is the set of values of L (look forward period) that the algorithm will #try (window_size)
#    The L that maximizes |tHat_B_1| (t-value) is choosen - which is the look-forward #period 
#    with the most significant trend. (optimization)
'''
def getBinsFromTrend(molecule, close, span):
    
    #Derive labels from the sign of t-value of trend line
    #output includes:
     # - t1: End time for the identified trend
     # - tVal: t-value associated with the estimated trend coefficient
      #- bin: Sign of the trend (1,0,-1)
    #The t-statistics for each tick has a different look-back window.
      
    #- idx start time in look-forward window
    #- dt1 stop time in look-forward window
    #- df1 is the look-forward window (window-size)
    #- iloc ? 
    
    out = pd.DataFrame(index=molecule, columns=['t1', 'tVal', 'bin', 'windowSize'])
    hrzns = range(*span)
    windowSize = span[1] - span[0]
    maxWindow = span[1]-1
    minWindow = span[0]
    for idx in close.index:
        idx += maxWindow
        if idx >= len(close):
            break
        df_tval = pd.Series(dtype='float64')
        iloc0 = close.index.get_loc(idx)
        if iloc0+max(hrzns) > close.shape[0]:
            continue
        for hrzn in hrzns:
            dt1 = close.index[iloc0-hrzn+1]
            df1 = close.loc[dt1:idx]
            df_tval.loc[dt1] = tValLinR(df1.values) #calculates t-statistics on period
        dt1 = df_tval.replace([-np.inf, np.inf, np.nan], 0).abs().idxmax() #get largest t-statistics calculated over span period

        print(df_tval.index[-1])
        print(dt1)
        print(abs(df_tval.values).argmax() + minWindow)
        out.loc[idx, ['t1', 'tVal', 'bin', 'windowSize']] = df_tval.index[-1], df_tval[dt1], np.sign(df_tval[dt1]), abs(df_tval.values).argmax() + minWindow #prevent leakage
    out['t1'] = pd.to_datetime(out['t1'])
    out['bin'] = pd.to_numeric(out['bin'], downcast='signed')

    #deal with massive t-Value outliers - they dont provide more confidence and they ruin the scatter plot
    tValueVariance = out['tVal'].values.var()
    tMax = 20
    if tValueVariance < tMax:
        tMax = tValueVariance

    out.loc[out['tVal'] > tMax, 'tVal'] = tMax #cutoff tValues > 20
    out.loc[out['tVal'] < (-1)*tMax, 'tVal'] = (-1)*tMax #cutoff tValues < -20
    return out.dropna(subset=['bin'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #snippet 5.3
    idx_range_from = 3
    idx_range_to = 10
    df1 = getBinsFromTrend(df.index, df['Close'], [idx_range_from,idx_range_to,1]) #[3,10,1] = range(3,10) This is the issue 
    tValues = df1['tVal'].values #tVal

    doNormalize = False
    #normalise t-values to -1, 1
    if doNormalize:
        np.min(tValues)
        minusArgs = [i for i in range(0, len(tValues)) if tValues[i] < 0]
        tValues[minusArgs] = tValues[minusArgs] / (np.min(tValues)*(-1.0))

        plus_one = [i for i in range(0, len(tValues)) if tValues[i] > 0]
        tValues[plus_one] = tValues[plus_one] / np.max(tValues)

    #+(idx_range_to-idx_range_from+1)
    plt.scatter(df1.index, df0.loc[df1.index].values, c=tValues, cmap='viridis') #df1['tVal'].values, cmap='viridis')
    plt.plot(df0.index, df0.values, color='gray')
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.show()
    plt.savefig('fig5.2.png')
    plt.clf()
    plt.df['Close']()
    plt.scatter(df1.index, df0.loc[df1.index].values, c=df1['bin'].values,  cmap='vipridis')

    #Test methods
    ols_tvalue = tValLinR( np.array([3.0, 3.5, 4.0]) )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least *several* issues with the code that you "found" (not just the one issue that you posted).

Before I go through some of the issues, let me say the following, which I may very well be wrong about, but based on my experience and on the way your question is worded (and the fact that you are "wanted to implement" code that you "found") it seems to me that you have minimal experience with coding and debugging.

Stackoverflow is ***not*** a place to ask others to debug your code.  That said, I will try to walk you though some of the steps that I took in trying to figure out what's going on with this code, and then perhaps point you to some resources where you can learn the same skills.

**Step 1:**

I took the code as you posted it, and copy/pasted it into a file that I named `so68871906.py`;  I then commented out the two lines at the top that are installing `yfinance` and `mplfinance` because I don't want to try to install them every time I run the code; rather I will install them once before running the code.

I then ran the code with the following result (similar to what you posted) ...

```py
dino@DINO:~/code/mplfinance/examples/scratch_pad/issues$ python so68871906.py
[*********************100%***********************]  1 of 1 completed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so68871906.py", line 84, in <module>
    df1 = getBinsFromTrend(df.index, df['Close'], [idx_range_from,idx_range_to,1]) #[3,10,1] = range(3,10) This is the issue
  File "so68871906.py", line 50, in getBinsFromTrend
    idx += maxWindow
  File "pandas/_libs/tslibs/timestamps.pyx", line 310, in pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps._Timestamp.__add__
TypeError: Addition/subtraction of integers and integer-arrays with Timestamp is no longer supported.  Instead of adding/subtracting `n`, use `n * obj.freq`
```

The key to successful debugging, especially in python, is to recognize that the Traceback gives you a lot of very important information.  **You just have to read through it very carefully.**  In the above case, the Traceback tells me:

1. The problem is with this line of code: `idx += maxWindow`.  This line of code is adding **`idx + maxWindow`** and reassigning the result back to `idx`
2. The error is a **`TypeError`** which tells me there is a problem with the **types** of the variables.  Since there are two variables on that line of code (`idx` and `maxWindow`) one may guess that one or both of those variables is the wrong **type** or otherwise incompatible with what the code is trying to do with the variable.
3. Based on the error message "Addition/subtraction of integers and integer-arrays with Timestamp is no longer supported", and the fact that we are doing addition of `idx` and `maxWindow`, you can guess that one of the variables is of type `integer` or `integer-array`, while the other is of type `Timestamp`.
4. You can verify the types by adding print statements just before the error occurs.  The code looks like this:

```py
    maxWindow = span[1]-1
    minWindow = span[0]
    for idx in close.index:
        print('type(idx)=',type(idx))
        print('type(maxWindow)=',type(maxWindow))
        idx += maxWindow
```

Now the output looks like this:

```py
dino@DINO:~/code/mplfinance/examples/scratch_pad/issues$ python so68871906.py
[*********************100%***********************]  1 of 1 completed
type(idx)= <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
type(maxWindow)= <class 'int'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so68871906.py", line 86, in <module>
    df1 = getBinsFromTrend(df.index, df['Close'], [idx_range_from,idx_range_to,1]) #[3,10,1] = range(3,10) This is the issue
  File "so68871906.py", line 52, in getBinsFromTrend
    idx += maxWindow
  File "pandas/_libs/tslibs/timestamps.pyx", line 310, in pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps._Timestamp.__add__
TypeError: Addition/subtraction of integers and integer-arrays with Timestamp is no longer supported.  Instead of adding/subtracting `n`, use `n * obj.freq`
```

Notice that indeed **`type(maxWindow)`** is **`int`** and **`type(idx)`** is **`Timestamp`**

The TypeError exception message further states "Instead of adding/subtracting `n`, use `n * obj.freq`" from which one may infer that `n` is intended to represent the integer.  It seems that the error is suggesting that we multiply the integer by some *frequency* before adding it to the Timestamp variable.  This is not entirely clear, so I **Googled "pandas add integer to Timestamp"** (because clearly that is what the code is trying to do).  All of the top answers suggest using `pandas.to_timedelta()` or [**`pandas.Timedelta()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html).

At this point I thought to myself: it makes sense that you can't just add an integer to a Timestamp, because what are you adding?  minutes? seconds? days? weeks?

However, you can add an integer number of one of these frequencies, in fact the [**`pandas.Timedelta()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html) constructor takes a `value` argument indicates a number of days, weeks, etc.

The data from `yf.download()` is daily (`interval='1d'`) which suggest that the integer should be multiplied by a `pandas.Timedelta` of 1 day.  I cannot be certain of this, because I don't have your textbook, so I am not 100% sure what the code is trying to accomplish there, but it is a reasonable guess, so I will change `idx += maxWindow` to

```py
idx += (maxWindow*pd.Timedelta('1 day'))
```

and see what happens:

```py
dino@DINO:~/code/mplfinance/examples/scratch_pad/issues$ python so68871906.py
[*********************100%***********************]  1 of 1 completed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so68871906.py", line 84, in <module>
    df1 = getBinsFromTrend(df.index, df['Close'], [idx_range_from,idx_range_to,1]) #[3,10,1] = range(3,10) This is the issue
  File "so68871906.py", line 51, in getBinsFromTrend
    if idx >= len(close):
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'Timestamp' and 'int'
```

**Step 2:**

The code passes the modified line of code (line 50), but now it's failing on the next line of code with a similar `TypeError` in that it doesn't support comparing ('>=') and integer and a Timestamp.  So next I try similarly modifying line 51 to:

```py
    if idx >= len(close)*pd.Timedelta('1 day'):
```

The result:

```py
dino@DINO:~/code/mplfinance/examples/scratch_pad/issues$ python so68871906.py
[*********************100%***********************]  1 of 1 completed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so68871906.py", line 84, in <module>
    df1 = getBinsFromTrend(df.index, df['Close'], [idx_range_from,idx_range_to,1]) #[3,10,1] = range(3,10) This is the issue
  File "so68871906.py", line 51, in getBinsFromTrend
    if idx >= len(close)*pd.Timedelta('1 day'):
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'Timestamp' and 'Timedelta'
```

This doesn't work either, as you can see (can't compare `Timestamp` and `Timedelta`).

**Step 3:**

Looking more closely at the code, it seems the code is trying to determine if adding `maxWindow` to `idx` has moved `idx` past the **end of the data**.

Looking a couple lines higher in the code, you can see that the variable `idx` comes from the list of `Timestamp` objects in `close.index`, so perhaps the correct comparison would be:

```py
    if idx >= close.index[-1]:
```

that is, comparing `idx` to the last possible `idx` value.  The result:

```py
dino@DINO:~/code/mplfinance/examples/scratch_pad/issues$ python so68871906.py
[*********************100%***********************]  1 of 1 completed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so68871906.py", line 84, in <module>
    df1 = getBinsFromTrend(df.index, df['Close'], [idx_range_from,idx_range_to,1]) #[3,10,1] = range(3,10) This is the issue
  File "so68871906.py", line 60, in getBinsFromTrend
    df_tval.loc[dt1] = tValLinR(df1.values) #calculates t-statistics on period
  File "so68871906.py", line 18, in tValLinR
    ols = sm1.OLS(close, x).fit()
NameError: name 'sm1' is not defined
```

**Step 4:**

Wow!  Great, we got past the errors on lines 50 and 51.  But now we have an error on line 18.  Indicating that the name `sm1` is not defined.  This suggests that either you did not copy all of the code that you should have, or perhaps there is something else that needs to be imported that would define `sm1` for the python interpreter.

---

So you see, this is the basic process of debugging your code.   Again the key, at least with python, is carefully reading the Traceback.  And again, Stackoverflow is ***not*** intended as a place to ask others to debug your code.  A little bit of searching online for things like "learn python" and "python debugging techniques" will yield a wealth of helpful information.

I hope this is pointing you in the right direction.  If for some reason I am way off base with this answer, let me know and I will delete it.

Comment: Hello Daniel, Thanks for taking the time and explaining the process of code debugging. It was very helpfull and I really appreciate your time. I will go through the code as you sugestted and try to understand exactly what is going on.